# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Pathname into String

Tags: ruby

I want to use this code to run rake task:

```
task :backup_and_delete_old_data => :environment do
      if defined?(Rails)
        require Rails.root + '/config/boot'
      else
        require '../../../config/boot'
      end
      require Rails.root + '/config/environment'

      factory_backup.each do |factory_data|
        puts ">> Backup and delete old #{factory_data.to_s.pluralize.humanize} data..."
        factory_data.factory_backup(backup_and_delete_old_data)
      end
    end
```

But when I run the rake task I get error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Pathname into String
```

for this line:

```
require Rails.root + '/config/boot'
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Try using `Rails.root.join('config', 'boot')`

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace of error.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to do `Rails.root.to_s`?
I guess the problem is that `Rails.root` is a `PathName`, not a `String`, as you can see on the below picture.

[image]

You can easily concatenate with the `+` operator if you cast the `Rails.root` to `String`. Please check the below picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have use the below format to require a ruby file,

```
require File.expand_path('../../../config/environment',  __FILE__)
```

Please specify correct **../** to correct location of file.